# Vertical continuous slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm looking for a slider to slide images vertically in a way that the scrolling is continuous (so that it looks like images are displayed in an infinite loop).

Does anyone already come accross what I'm looking for?

Comment: If using Flash in an option, [activeden](http://activeden.net/) is a good place to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

This very nice plugin will do what you need:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html

Comment: Thanks for all your responses.I used "jcarousel" plugin. http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_vertical.html